# Screen tearing Intel HD 5500

Tags: graphic-drivers, display, intel, graphics

My laptop is thinkpad T450s and there is very bad screen tearing when I move windows around or when I watch videos. My CPU is `Intel HD 5500` with integrated graphics(core i5).

I looked around but I only found a solution for Ubuntu. I found same [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/667090/screen-tearing-intel-graphics-5500) and this is the [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/667466/screen-tearing-in-ubuntu-with-nvidia-intel-graphics/668590#668590).

I am not sure if that can be used for elementary OS. 
It didn't fix anything. Is there a solution for screen tearing on elementary OS?

I have also tried this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IBtpXh728HU) and it didn't work.

**EDIT:** It does work, you just need to restart, which I forgot to do. See solution below.

Comment: :  Please drop at http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33627/ravan-and-dobo

Comment: I just set the video output as OpenGL, and the problem was solved. (intel HD4600)

Comment: Did not solve at all, tried to reboot and desktop manager just won't start.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out I just had to restart the computer for it to take effect(of course!).
Type the following into the terminal to get rid of screen tearing for intel CPU/integrated graphics. In this case I tested it for intel HD graphics 5500 on my Lenovo Thinkpad T450s.

```
sudo mkdir /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/
echo -e 'Section "Device" \n Identifier "Intel Graphics" \n Driver "Intel" \n Option "TearFree" "true" \nEndSection' | sudo tee /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf
```

The file "/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf" should contain:

```
Section "Device"
Identifier  "Intel Graphics"
Driver      "Intel"
Option      "TearFree"    "true"
EndSection
```

Comment: Thanks - This also worked for me in Ubuntu 16.10 beta 2, though I did have to create the file in /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d

Answer (score 0):

You could also try. Helped with graphical abnormalities for me on an Intel 7200U with integrated graphics.

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge xserver-xorg
```